# plsql raise_application_error with predefined exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone please let me know what mistake I m making here?
Can we have a predefined exception with raise_application_error?

```
declare
        s1 emp.sal %type;
begin
        select sal into s1 from emp where ename='SOMDUTT';
        if no_data_found then
            raise_application_error(20001, 'somdutt is not there');
        end if;
        if(s1 > 10000) then
            raise_application_error(20002, 'somdutt is earing a lot');
        end if;
        update emp set sal=sal+500 where ename='SOMDUTT';
end;
/
```

> if no_data_found then
>          *
>       ERROR at line 5:
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
>       PLS-00382: expression is of the wrong type
>       ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: `no_data_found` is an exception, not a variable that you can test with `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the condition to check `no_data_found` to an exception block.

Also, you can only use an error number in the range of `-20000` to `-20999`

```
declare
        s1 emp.sal%type;
begin
        select sal into s1 from emp where ename='SOMDUTT';

        if s1 > 10000  then
            raise_application_error(-20002, 'somdutt is earing a lot');
        end if;
        update emp set sal=sal+500 where ename='SOMDUTT';
     EXCEPTION

     when no_data_found then
            raise_application_error(-20001, 'somdutt is not there');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, so it means we cannot use raise_application_error with a predefined exception like no_data_found in the if block?

Comment: @Nav : `no_data_found` will be raised by default when the `select into` returns no rows. If you want to raise it forcefully, you can still do it using a `raise no_data_found` but it won't display the error message you want.